Cant add LWC Action on Product Object, but I can add it on Account or custom object
I am trying to add Action button LWC on Product but even after adding it on layout its not visible. This action if created on other Object such as Account or any custom object works fine. Has anyone added a Action button for Aura or LWC in product layout? Please help
Steps to reproduce:

Add a very simple Aura/LWC component
Simple Aura example:

    <aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:card title="Hello World">
        <!-- Contact list goes here -->
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>   


Add it as action on Product layout

Its not visible on Product record page but its visible everywhere.


